# How to avoid main script to be executed in / pages using react?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, react-router

I have a problem.

I'm using react for my website. And what i want to do is to have completely different page after / (e.g.  www.test.com/FirstPage www.test.com/SecondPage) like a portfolio and i want them to have its own nav body and footer with its own js files and etc. But i face some issues

Now i have my main website like www.test.com and i am creating different one in www.test.com/differentone , and all css classes(if they have the same name as in main website) and javascript executes too. How do i avoid that, i want it to be completely different without inheriting any css or js for / websites. Does routing even allows pages to be independent ?

Cause even javascript file from main page tries to fire when i am in /SecondPage but it doesn't find content that's in main web page and it crashes.

Naming for every other file can be completely different but it does the same. I hope i explained it clearly enough to understand

[I have my folder now like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jxWFE.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can handle this with react-router. Here below is a small example code.

```
  <Router history={browserHistory}>
    <Route path='/dashboard' component={App} onEnter={requireAuth} >
      <IndexRoute component={MainContent} onEnter={requireAuth} />
      <Route path='/notes' component={Notelist} onEnter={requireAuth}></Route>   
    </Route> 
    <Route path='/invite/*' component={Invite}></Route>  
    <Route path='/' component={Login}> </Route>
    <Route path='/changepassword/*' component={ChangePassword}></Route>
  </Router>
```

This is how you can handle your components with different css wrapping inside Route tags. Here Login component has different css whereas App component is the main dashboard page with different css.

You can keep all your css files in styles folder and call it in main.js something like this.

```
 import './styles/main.scss';
```

Comment: well, i exactly have it like this. And it reads different css files, but the problem is that it reads all anyway, no matter in which route i am i can even not include css but it still reads. What i mean is like: for example i have navbar with .navbar class in my MainComponent and in maincomponent.css are some .navbar styling. And when i add the component (e.g. AnotherComponent) route and have navbar with the same .navbar class it reads maincomponents.css even if i'm not importing it to AnotherComponent. Same with javascript files, doesnt matter where i am it executes main components js too